# DataGridView shows several items selected even if MultiSelect property is set to false

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using *System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView* and I have set `MultiSelect = false` and `SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect` , this doesn't allow user to select multiple items. While doing testing I found when we use the down arrow <kbd>↓</kbd> to change the selection - in normal speed it works fine, but when you perform it in a faster speed, it marks some other item as selected.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView" is not an ASP.NET control. Are you using ASP.NET or not?

Comment: Check the SelectedRows.Count property, to see if there is really more than one item selected, or if it is just the rendering of the DataGridView onto the screen that is borked.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Question is tagged for **winfroms** so its Winform control.

Comment: I am not surprised; DataGridView is far from perfect, it has many know issues, i myself have found atleast 3.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the KeyDownEvent, use the KeyUpEvent.